# What event can help us to catch complete map rendering in Openlayers?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3, openlayers-5

I'm creating an OpenLayers draw application where I let users draw shapes and then I allow them to print maps on pdf by zooming into the drawn shape.
My current code is working for - Draw Geometry, Zoom to the geometry.
For printing, I'm currently using

```
map.once('postcompose', function(e){
var canvas = e.context.canvas;
data = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
doc.addImage(data, "jpg", 10, 50, 190, 120);
})
```

but the problem is it doesn't wait for complete loading of basemap, because of which I'm getting blurred background.
[image]

how can I fix this?

Comment: In OpenLayers 5 and above use `rendercomplete` as in https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.0/examples/export-pdf.html
In earlier versions you need to count the loading tiles as in https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/export-pdf.htm

Comment: I tried `rendercomplete` but I'm getting event.context.canvas undefined

Comment: Are you using OL6?  There can be multiple canvases which you need to combine https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/export-pdf.html